# how to vertically stick second row elements to first row elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a problem. i defined many element as inline block. i want this elements fit vertically their parent.with no white space. 
I try:

```
.parent
{
    display: block;
}
.parent .elements
{
    display: inline-block;![enter image description here][1]
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

but not work.
I try this solution : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

but it hasn't any useful answer for this issue.
 please visit this image to understand what I want :
http://gilace.com/describe2.gif

Comment: You're going to need to give more information than "but not work". You'll need to describe in far more detail what it is currently doing that isn't lining up with your expectations of what it should do.

Comment: I attached an image to illuminate what I want to do. each element stick top element with no space with different height.

Comment: But you need to describe how your code fails to achieve what you want it to do.

Comment: What have you tried? We need to see some of your CSS, perhaps in a jsfiddle.

Comment: http://gridster.net/#demos || http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index2.html || ???

Comment: You need a _javascript framework_ like [**masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to achieve this effect reliably and cross broswer. Flexbox is a more horizontal approach and doesn't match up with the example you show in your question.

Comment: I update this post, I have not enough reputation to upload more images...

Comment: @JRulle : it is exactly what i want. but do you have a CSS solution for this issue?

Comment: @hoceyn Pure CSS solution here, but be aware, older browsers don't support CSS3 multicolumn: http://w3bits.com/demo/responsive-css-masonry/  See there for browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn   Same idea for bootstrap: http://www.bootply.com/120682

Comment: @hoceyn sadly no... this is a little too heavy for CSS. You might be able to come up with something custom using CSS though – do your blocks have some sort of logical order or are they random? (I am thinking create three columns and add the sub elements into them)

Comment: @JRulle sadly these are logical list and must be following another box in responsive view ...

Comment: @hoceyn, if you want to try a pure CSS that is backward compatible with IE, check this out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/83L4vs37/)

Comment: @JRulle Really simple solution, looks great indeed

Answer (score 0):

I don undertand your questions very  well, but maybe using:

```
display: inline-table;
```

instead of:

```
display: inline-block;
```

would be a first step.